# SVG path with c and long sequence of numbers. What does it mean

Tags: svg

Here is a path tag I have trouble understanding, it is rendered into a nice curve

```
<path fill="none" stroke="deeppink" stroke-width="3" 
d="M62.9 14.9c-25-7.74-56.6 4.8-60.4 24.3-3.73 19.6 21.6 35 39.6 37.6 
42.8 6.2 72.9-53.4 116-58.9 65-18.2 191 101 215 28.8 5-16.7-7-49.1-34
-44-34 11.5-31 46.5-14 69.3 9.38 12.6 24.2 20.6 39.8 22.9 91.4 9.05 
102-98.9 176-86.7 18.8 3.81 33 17.3 36.7 34.6 2.01 10.2.124 21.1-5.18 30.1" />
```

I do know that what immediately follows `c` are two control points and one destination point. But what are the rest of numbers? Are they also bezier curves but with `c` commands omitted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have found this out by reading the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#paths-PathData).

> The command letter can be eliminated on subsequent commands if the same command is used multiple times in a row

If there is a sequence of path commands that are the same, then you don't need to repeat the command (e.g. the `c`). You can just repeat the coordinate parameters.  So your path is equivalent to:

```
M 62.9 14.9
c -25-7.74-56.6 4.8-60.4 24.3
c -3.73 19.6 21.6 35 39.6 37.6 
c 42.8 6.2 72.9-53.4 116-58.9
c 65-18.2 191 101 215 28.8
c 5-16.7-7-49.1-34-44
c -34 11.5-31 46.5-14 69.3
c 9.38 12.6 24.2 20.6 39.8 22.9
c 91.4 9.05 102-98.9 176-86.7
c 18.8 3.81 33 17.3 36.7 34.6
c 2.01 10.2.124 21.1-5.18 30.1
```